# Prokhorov's Theorem, tightness implies convergence of a subsequence

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm trying to apply Prokhorov's Theorem on the measure space $M$, defined as the space of non-negative, finite measures on $[0,T] \times \mathbb R^d$ with the weak topology in the following sense:

Given a tight sequence of probability measures $P_n$ on $M$, not elements of $M$ but rather probability measures over $M$, can I conclude that there is a weakly convergent subsequence? Do I need $M$ to be complete and separable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, any tight sequence $(P_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of Radon probabilities on $M$ has a subsequence that converges weakly to Radon probability and there is no need for any additional assumption on $M$.

It can be shown that the space of nonnegative finite Radon measures on a [Polish space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space) is always a Polish space under the weak topology (*cf*. for example [Prokhorov's original paper](https://www.mathnet.ru/eng/tvp4997), thm. 1.11, or Bourbaki's [*Integration*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-07931-7), chap. IX, §5, prop. 10). So under the weak topologies, your space $M$ is Polish and the space $N$ of nonnegative finite Radon measures on $M$ is also Polish and in particular is metrizable.

The metrizability of $N$ tells you that a tight sequence of elements of $N$ has a subsequence that converges weakly in $N$ if and only if it has an adherent point in $N$ for the weak topology, the existence of which is given by the relative compactness property given by Prokhorov's theorem.

Comment: Throughout your answer you speak of Radon measures. What allows us to consider only Radon measures?

Comment: @FlorianEnte A bounded complex measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a Polish space is always Radon.